# CLLocationManager broke. No longer updating location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Before anyone wonders, yes I did read through the other solutions, my program has recently broken mysteriously. I have made no changes to my code, and just today tried to run a simulation for a friend to take a look at my app, and I get the dreaded:

> Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Well I double checked my plist and yes both

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

are still there.

Here is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mainMapView setDelegate:self];
    [mainMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [manager setDelegate:self];
    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [manager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [manager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

    [search setDelegate:self];
    [search setAlpha:0];

    annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    model = [[DataModel alloc]init];
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: where do you init manager? Show us the code.

Comment: Paul had the answer, I init manager in a separate method which was not getting called. Thank you for pointing that out. I hate the simple oversights...

Comment: No problem, I'll make that an answer, not a comment. That way we can both get some fake internet points for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use both permission requests

`[manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
 [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` ?

Did you add the proper keys for the permissions the you .plist file?

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Comment: Yes, both keys are in my info.plist with a user prompt for the string value. I use both permission requests out of convenience. When I run a simulation I will comment one or the other out

Comment: Just wondering, if you're using the simulator, did you tell the simulator to simulate the location?

Answer (score 0):

Paul Cezanne pointed out my embarrassing oversight. Thank you very much for your reply. I was initializing my manager in a separate method which was not getting called. Turns out I was actually using an older version from my repo than the most current one.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that manager is not nil! It is easy to overlook this. Just put a breakpoint in your viewDidLoad and see what manager is set to.

Another common way to get this to fail is to init your manager but to not assign it to a property. When you are running ARC it will get released when no longer in scope. Just make it a property in your view controller object.